# Is it correct and natural to say "just to finish my thought" when you were interrupted and you want to finish what you wanted to say?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Is it correct and natural to say *just to finish my thought* when you were interrupted and you want to finish what you wanted to say? For example:

> **Just to finish my thought**, the best course of action would be to hire more people.

If that sounds off, what would you say?

Comment: 100% natural to me

Comment: I'm leaving this question open because it's about **something in particular** -- the correct usage of "just to finish my thought", not a request to broadly **improve the phrasing**. If you're voting to close a question, the least you can do is be familiar with the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely sounds good to me as a native English speaker. It's also worth considering politeness, because depending on your tone when you say that, it could come off as rude since you would be suggesting that whoever interrupted you did so inappropriately. If the interruption was related to what you were saying, you could make it a little more smooth by saying something like:

> Well said. In line with those ideas, the best course of action would be to hire more people.

or

> Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I agree with you and think that the best course of action would be to hire more people.

If the interruption was a digression that was unrelated to your point, you could even say:

> As I was saying, the best course of action would be to hire more people.

Or your original statement would work. I would say overall, there is nothing wrong with your original statement. It's just hard to give advice without the context around that conversation.